# implementing stripe with strong customer authentication

Tags: php, stripe-payments, strong-customer-authentication

I am trying to create a word-press plugin with stripe that support strong customer authentication. charges with stripe is working fine for me. I have referred this link https://www.codexworld.com/stripe-payment-gateway-integration-php/ for creating payments. Any such reference link for sca implementation in stripe? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just moved my company over from the old Charges API to SCA. It wasn't pretty. I'm a back-end engineer so I'm only going to tackle the back-end components needed to make this work. If you want a fully customised front-end too, you're going to need to read the Stripe docs and do a lot more bounces around form submit -> enhanced validation -> collect more data -> submit more data. This workflow was too complicated and thankfully my company went with the Stripe checkout solution for this part.

I work for a SaaS company and we take money for room bookings, so we have non-fungible time dependent 'stock' items. Since we sell booking slots on behalf of our customers we also have Stripe connected accounts in play. Basically, all the nightmare corner cases you could wish for. Since the checkout session is live for 24 hours we have to allocate then collect - if you start the process and then go for lunch there is no guarantee that when the payment is processed the room you want will still be free for your timeslot.

My process looks like:

Back-end calls Stripe and starts a checkout session with `Session::create()`. Set your `payment_method_types` and `line_items` in this as well as your return URLs. Also send up a `payment_intent_data`. Mine looks like this:

```
            'payment_intent_data' => [
                'transfer_data' => [
                    'destination' => 'acct_ number of linked account',
                ],
                'capture_method' => 'manual',
                'description' => 'description of item',
                'statement_descriptor' => 'description of item, max 22 chars',
            ],
```

Obviously if you don't have connected accounts then omit the `transfer_data` but definitely include both descriptors. If you are sure of your stock levels (eg: digital goods) you can change your `capture_method` to `automatic`.

On a return from Stripe I send the session key (`sk_`) to the front-end who then hand this over to Stripe's payment form. This is the point you'll need to do a lot more work if you want a totally custom front-end. Good luck.

When the checkout session is successful I have a webhook event on `checkout.session.completed` to call my API, as well as handling the URL returns from the front-end. I keep extra data in my database about the payment state so I only handle each return once.

Either return leads me back to the session - the ID is in the front-end links and the session can be retrieved from `$session = $event->data->object` in the webhook callback. You can then get the intent out of the session with `$intent = PaymentIntent::retrieve($session->payment_intent);`

At this point, I handle the various status codes in the PaymentIntent;

```
requires_payment_method
requires_confirmation
requires_action
canceled
requires_capture
succeeded
```

The one I'm really interested in is `requires_capture` where I then check to see if the resource is still free. If it is, I `$intent->capture()` to finalise the payment and create the booking for the user. You can handle each of them as needed by your business process.

If you are dealing with connected accounts you will also need to load the transfer item associated with the PaymentIntent Charge object and then load the Charge referenced in the `destination_payment` field (you can load charges with the `py_` key). Then set the `description` and `statement_descriptor` fields and save the charge back so your connected customers know what the payment is for.